# Use pixels not points in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, retina-display

In xcode, when using xibs or storyboards, xcode automatically uses points (one pixel on non-retina, four on retina displays). This was convenient four years ago when we had to develop for both retina and non-retina displays, but Apple hasn't sold a phone without a retina display in years. I don't even bother with the non-@2x versions anymore. Is there any way to override the points and use pixels? It is also frustrating when I want to move/stretch an image ONE pixel, not two.

Comment: This is a good question, but I fear the answer is "no" so far. We've had some trouble getting rid of the non @2x images because of Interface Builder. Make sure to open an enhancement over at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that both the iPad 2 and iPad Mini (original) are still being sold by Apple, so some users are still buying devices without Retina displays. Also, who knows what will change in the future. Perhaps there will someday be a model with 1.5x density instead of 2x density? Who knows?

Comment: @user1118321 Fair enough, but I still would like to be toggle-able to switch between points and pixels. One time I wanted a one-pixel line separating some elements and ended up having to make a special image just for that because I couldn't move the retina image by one pixel. It is really annoying.

Comment: the coordinate system in iOS uses floats, not int, you can use +0.5 to represent a 1 pixel increase

Answer (score 0):

You can change the bounds of a `UIView` to twice the width and height of its frame, but I would strongly recommend against this, it will make your code confusing. I don't think you should assume anything about the number of pixel per point, Apple have specifically design iOS to be pixel agnostic, you shouldn't try by passing that.

Comment: That would be weird... I am just trying to find out a way to toggle between points and pixels just like in illustrator or photoshop.

Comment: @AttilaTheFun, a lot of computer screens had 72 pixels per inch, which matches exactly one point per pixel, and until recently most computer displays stayed roughly at that level. Recent iOS devices have over 250 pixels per inch. With this, converting between points and pixels doesn't make a whole lot of sense anymore.